# Issues with implementing a doubly-linked list

Tags: python, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm making doubly-linked list class.

```
def remove(self, item):
    current=self.__head
    prev=None
    found=False
    if(self.__size>=1):
        for i in range (0,self.__size):
            if(current.getData()==item):
                found=True
                pos=i#save the position to pop
                i=self.__size#leave the loop
            else:
                prev=current
                current=current.getNext()

        if(found==True):#excute only if the item is found
            if(prev==None):#first item found
                if(self.__size==1):
                    self.__head==None
                    self.__tail==None
                    current.setNext(None)
                    current.setPrevious(None)
                else:#size bigger than 2
                    self.__head==current.getNext()
                    current.setNext(None)
            else:
                if(current.getNext()==None):#last item found
                    self.__tail==prev
                    current.setPrevious(None)
                    prev.setNext(None)
                else:
                    Next=current.getNext()
                    current.setNext(None)
                    current.setPrevious(None)
                    Next.setPrevious(prev)
                    prev.setNext(Next)
            self.pop(pos)
            self.__size-=1
```

This is what I did so far. If I run the code below

```
 for i in range(0, 10):
    int_list2.add(i)
    int_list2.remove(1)
    int_list2.remove(3)
    int_list2.remove(2)
    int_list2.remove(0)
    print(int_list2)
```

these are the output that I get

```
0

1

2

3

4 3

5 4 3

6 5 4 3

7 6 5 4 3

8 7 6 5 4 3

9 8 7 6 5 4
```

I'm expecting first 4 rows (0~3) to display nothing and from the fifth one as 4, 6th one as 5 4....and so on.

At the end I want 9 8 7 6 5 4

How do I fix the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem is in the first part of your if statement in the for loop:

```
for i in range (0,self.__size):
        if(current.getData()==item):
            found=True
            pos=i#save the position to pop
            i=self.__size#<--- doesn't leave the loop 
        else:
            prev=current
            current=current.getNext()
```

Setting `i=self.__size` does not exit the loop. Use `break` instead.

This makes it so that when you find the item you keep iterating through the loop and `current` is not the item that you want to remove. Instead `current` is the value of the last node that you look at in the for loop.

Also you are using `==` when I'm sure you mean assignment `=` so on these lines:

```
self.__head==None   #should be self.__head=None
self.__tail==None   #should be self.__tail=None
current.setNext(None)
current.setPrevious(None)
```

change the `==` to a single `=`. I think you do it a few times in your `if(found==True):` block. These lines are just evaluating the boolean expression and throwing the value away.

Change those things, and let me know if that fixes it.

Also, just a little tip:

If you have a boolean variable (like `found`) you don't need to check `found==True` because it evaluates to the same value as just `found`. i.e.:

```
if(found==True):
   ...
```

is the same as:

```
if(found):
   ...
```